# mobileNetworkCode returns "VZW" instead of the numeric mobile network code

Tags: iphone, ios

I have tried this code:

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *netinfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
CTCarrier *carrier = [netinfo subscriberCellularProvider];
if(carrier != nil)
{
    NSString *mnc = [carrier mobileNetworkCode];
    NSLog(@" mnc is %@ ", mnc);
}
```

It works as I expected when the carrier is AT&T.
I got mnc is 410.

However, when the carrier is Verizon. I got "mnc is VZW".
**Is this a correct behavior of the API?
Any other way that I can obtain the numeric mobile network code?**

note: Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCarrier/Reference/Reference.html) says the method should return...

> A read-only NSString object that represents the numeric mobile network
>   code for the user’s cellular service provider.

I'm not sure what I have done wrong or something's wrong with my phone :-)

Comment: I bet that since Verizon was kind of an afterthought, this was what they did instead. Just use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what model u use. I also got VZW when testing with iPhone 4 (iOS 6).
AFAIK, it's the only way to get MNC.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen both 480 and VZW returned on Verizon devices. Some other networks also sometimes return 3 letter codes, such as SPR for sprint.